# QMap<QString, QVector<QString>> Access QVector C++ Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vector

I am trying to use this map from within my class.

```
static QMap<QString,QVector<QString>> myMap = {
        {"aaa",       {"bbb",     "ccc"} },
        {"ddd",       {"eee",     "fff"} },
        {"ggg",       {"hhh"      "jjj"} },
};
```

But when I try to access the first or second element within QVector i always get the two strings appended.

When I execute the line below, I would expect "bbb", but what I get is "bbbccc".

```
QString ret = myMap.value("aaa").first();
```

What I expect is:

myMap.value("aaa") returns a QVector -> the first element sould be "bbb";

Same is valid for: (expect: "ccc", but getting "bbbccc").

```
QString ret = myMap.value("aaa").last();
```

I don't really understand why. Anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're missing a comma:

```
{"ggg",       {"hhh"      "jjj"} },
                    ^here
```

Comment: ah, man, to many hours before the monitor I guess, thank you very much!

Comment: @user3482407 remember to take a break and feel the sun on your face every few hours - it helps! :-)